# Why does running under "make" alter shared library load addresses?

Tags: java, linux, makefile, shared-libraries

a colleague discovered that when running the command

`java -Xmx1024m -version`

from within a makefile he was getting the message `'Failed to instantiate heap; 1G requested'`

But running it from the command line works fine. This is on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 using a 32-bit JVM (64-bit works fine).

After further investigation he discovered:

> The java shared libraries normally
>   get loaded at the end of the process
>   address space, so addresses around
>   0x7... If java is being run by a make
>   process, the libraries get loaded in
>   the middle of the address space, at
>   addresses around 0x4....

Does anyone know why make is causing the libraries to be loaded at a different location and if there is anyway to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

The load address is merely a preferred load address. If it is already mapped and used due to another so/dll then the so/dll is relocated. Anyway with ASLR the situation is even worse, you never know where the stuff gets visible in user space.

EDIT:

I could reproduce the problem with 2GB (-Xmx2048m) but no idea what technically is exactly the problem. I think it has to do with the way the process relates to make / how it is spawned

```
jaap@ubuntu-desktop:~$ make
java -Xmx2048m -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: But why would it only already be mapped when running under make? Don't freshly minted processes start out with a blank slate for their virtual memory mappings under linux?

Comment: ouch you're completely right, it sounds like an interesting effect. On my bookmark. I have to figure out if I can reproduce this at home.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar effect and tracked down the reason:

- the load address for dynamic libraries is, generally, whatever mmap(0) happens to allocate. So what's different here is where the kernel is putting memory into the process address spcace.
- the kernel used to allocate memory from low userspace addresses upwards, but switched to top down. See https://lwn.net/Articles/91829/
- if a subprocess is started with RLIMIT_STACK set to infinity, the kernel switches to the old (legacy) bottom-up allocation (legacy order can also be forced with a personality bit, but that's probably not what's going on here).
- make 3.81 introduced a bug where it started subprocesses with RLIMIT_STACK set to infinity
- this was fixed in make 3.82: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?22010
- in at least one commercial distro, the make is 3.81 but appears to have this bug fix applied and doesn't suffer from the memory order issue.

So if you are using standard 3.81 make, that's likely the issue. If not, then maybe something else is setting RLIMIT_STACK to infinity in the subprocess. If it's not RLIMIT_STACK, it may be the personality. Look at /proc/self/personality at the command line and under make, and see if it's got bit 200000 set.